# Is there a way to make a PLSQL script that lists all columns that IS NULL for every record in a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working with a huge database with several columns and records. I want to browse a specific table and make a list of the columns that are empty for every record. 
Is this possible without refering to all the specific column names?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you want to check this for every table or for only 1 table?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below script to find out the null columns in your database -

```
DECLARE
    COUNT_COL INT;
    SQL_STR VARCHAR2(100); 
BEGIN
    FOR I IN (SELECT OBJECT_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
              FROM USER_OBJECTS UO
              JOIN USER_TAB_COLS UTC ON UO.OBJECT_NAME = UTC.TABLE_NAME) LOOP
          SQL_STR := 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ' || I.OBJECT_NAME || ' WHERE ' || i.COLUMN_NAME || ' IS NOT NULL';
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STR INTO COUNT_COL;
          IF COUNT_COL = 0 THEN
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I.COLUMN_NAME);
          END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e92a8c99aa18f89f542c6b8aaa85c04d) is the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solution. It seems to do the work I want. However, when running this in Oracle SQL Developer, I get the following error:
Error report:
ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 20000 bytes
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 32
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 97
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 112
ORA-06512: at line 14
20000. 00000 -  "%s"

Seems like the DBMS_OUTPUT LIMIT IS MET

Comment: Yes. It seems you have too many columns in your DB as blank. You may try putting them in a table using insert statement rather than printing. That might a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but if you have a lot data it will last a long time.

```
create table xxx as select * from dba_objects where rownum < 10000;
```

prepare test table get table stats. It can be long lasting process.

```
begin
 dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'XXX',estimate_percent =>100);
 -- ..
 -- others tables to analizye
end;
```

Generate reports.

```
select table_name,column_name from user_tab_cols where coalesce(low_value,high_value) is null and table_name in('XXX');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try for all record in table:

```
SELECT a.owner, a.table_name, b.column_name
 FROM all_tables a, all_tab_columns b
WHERE a.table_name = '<TABLE_NAME>'
AND a.table_name = b.table_name
AND a.num_rows = b.num_nulls
```

For all table

```
SELECT a.owner, a.table_name, b.column_name
  FROM all_tables a, all_tab_columns b
 WHERE a.table_name = b.table_name
 AND a.num_rows = b.num_nulls
```